# How to read local textfile using html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am trying the following to write the contents of a local text file (version.txt) to the screen, but it isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script charset="utf-8" src = "jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script charset="utf-8" src = "cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>



<script>
function test()
{
    $.get("version.txt", function(data) {
     document.write(data);
    });
}
</script>

<body>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Print version.txt</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

update: this works, I was just mistyping the name of the jquery file I was including.

Comment: What's your console say? It has all the info! It could be the simple fact that you never closed the `test()` function (I properly indented your code, the closing brace is now clearly visible)

Comment: You're missing a closing brace...

Answer (score 2):

1. You're missing a closing brace. The console will clearly tell you about invalid Javascript if you look.
2. You can't use document.write after the page has loaded. (Well you can, but you won't get the result you want.) Use jQuery append() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wheater it is typo or not you are missing closing brace for function test

```
<script>
function test()
{
    $.get("version.txt", function(data) {
     document.write(data);
    });

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just forgot to type the brace in the question. The real problem was that I mistyped the name of the jquery file that I was including.